# How can i create a time table for school and having rows of periods and columns as classes and date

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
date 
class1 
class2 
class3 
class4
class5
class6
```

and

```
Hour 9-10
10-11
11-12
12-1
2-3
3-4
4-5

       Day         class1    class2     class3    class4    class5    class6
```

9-10            Mon         faculty1  faculty2   faculty3  faculty4  faculty5   faculty6 ---here next hour Faculty should be auto generate like that

10-11                 f2          f3        f4         f5        f6        f1

11-12                 f3          f4        f5         f6       f1          f2

12-1                  f4          f5        f6         f1       f2          f3

1-2                                       Lunch-Break

2-3                   f5         f6         f1         f2      f3           f4

3-4                   f6        f1          f2         f3       f4          f5

4-5                  Games     library     games      lib       games      lib

in aspx.cs having two dropdownlist of class and Facultyid when i select these two i have to show Timetable in gridview formate

How can increment dynamically of  Facultyids

Comment: please provide proper Table Structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to visualize your table structure based on what you need to store vs how you want to report on it. What you have works obviously, but if you store it in a more generic way it can be extended/changed easier.

**Note** this doesn't exactly address some of the problems you want to solve (such as tracking lunch breaks, but I think it's a step in the right direction).

Here's what I'd start with:

```
Student
-Id
-Name

Class
-Id
-Name

PeriodType //constraint for periods 1-6
-Id
-Name (maybe name)

StudentSchedule
-StudentId
-ClassId
-PeriodTypeId
-DateTime
```

This structure could use some work. You'll probably want to be able to track additional data:

- Ability to track if a student reported to a specific period/class (could be done with another column in `StudentSchedule`)
- etc